Handling CORS with Wildcard Subdomains in Flask-SocketIO
I'm trying to configure Flask-SocketIO to handle CORS for multiple subdomains (e.g., cors_allowed_origins='*.domain.com').
allowed_origins = [
'https://*.domain.com',
'http://*.localdomain.com' # testzone
]

cors = CORS(flask, resources={r"/*": {"supports_credentials": True, "origins": allowed_origins}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins=allowed_origins)

However, I noticed that cors_allowed_origins does not support wildcards directly for flask_socketIO nor for flask_cors. unless it's from all domains (e.g., cors_allowed_origins='*'). I know I could make a list for all my subdomains but that would take so long since I created a lot of subdomains.
Could you please advise on the best approach to handle CORS with wildcard subdomains for Socket.IO?
Is there a recommended way to configure this or any workarounds?
Is there a simple function I can use?
Thanks in advance!

This isn't currently supported in Flask-SocketIO. What you can do is not use the internal CORS support in Flask-SocketIO and instead build your own CORS handler that does what you need as a WSGI middleware that wraps your Flask application.

I'm seeking a straightforward and effective method to iterate through my subdomains and return them as a list. Specifically, I need a function that uses a for loop to accomplish this task.
